# We use the api of here maps in order to extract a matrix of predicted times and also real time to create optimization. Times are way longer then real

Tags: matrix, time, here-api, here-maps-rest

We use the api of here maps in order to extract a matrix of predicted times and also real time to create routing optimization. The times are significantly longer than those of Google and Waze. was set on Car. Are there additional settings that are required, which makes the time matrix more accurate?

Accurate time matrix here maps